# How to set the default print preview page based on a date in Crystal Report, when the report is launched?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have been working on this for a while and can't figure out how to get it resolved. I have a crystal report in calendar format. The report always has 12 pages of a year, with each page for 1 month.

What I would like to accomplish: When the report is opened and the default first page is based on the current date's month. E.g. When today's date is 02/13/2023, the default page showing is February's page. When today's date is 04/05/2023, the default page showing is April's page.

Crystal report always shows the first page as default page, meaning, always starts from January's page. This is not user-friendly for users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to preview the report: Crystal Report Designer or a Crystal Runtime viewer?

Would you be open to a solution that provides the data via a web page? At least one of the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation/scheduling tools listed on [Ken Hamady's web site](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#desktopsched) allows you to take schedule data in a Crystal report and convert it to an interactive web schedule with options for day/week/workweek/monthl views (that automatically default to the current date).